# Batch file to list all subfolder paths

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to write a command that runs from location of the program. The program asks user to type in a folder to search for, when the folder is found, I need a list of directories to its subfolders. Below is my code so far:

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO Enter name for your target search folder
SET /P searchf=[Please type desired search forder]
for /d %%a in ("%searchf%".) do dir /ad /on /s /b "%%a" >> %searchf%.txt
GOTO End
:End
```

Assuming the target folder is called "`test`", I want to have a result like this:

```
C:\Users\IT\test\pany\all
C:\Users\IT\test\ondy\part\clear
C:\Users\IT\pany\test\check\apps
C:\Users\IT\pand\all\check\test
```

So far my code returns dir till where the "test" was found.

Comment: Read http://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html and http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, I still have not solved it. Code now lists file paths, I need to have only folder and subfolder path. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JosefZ pointed out, wild cards will help:

```
ECHO OFF
ECHO Enter name for your target search folder
SET /P searchf=[Please type desired search forder]
dir /ad /on /s /b "*%searchf%*"
```

Since there is only one search term, you do not need a for loop.

Using a variable file name I considered difficult, that's why I first changed it to be a fixed filename, until I figured out that for having a list of directories on the screen you can use the dir output directly.

Comment: don't you want to use `%sarchf%` instead of undefined `%%a`?